# R. Remove everything between to delimiter characters

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data frame with this kind of expression in column C:

```
GT_rs9628326:N_rs9628326
GT_rs1111:N_rs1111
GT_rs8374:N_rs8374
```

Using R, I want to remove everything between the first "T" and ":", as well as everything after the "N". I know this can be done with gsub. I would get:

```
GT:N
GT:N
GT:N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
gsub("_\\w+","",s)
```

giving

```
[1] "GT:N" "GT:N" "GT:N"
```

**Data**

```
s <- c("GT_rs9628326:N_rs9628326","GT_rs1111:N_rs1111","GT_rs8374:N_rs8374")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be splitting the strings by `:` and then replace non necessary text in order to collapse all together again by same split symbol (I have used @ThomasIsCoding data thanks):

```
#Data
v1 <- c("GT_rs9628326:N_rs9628326","GT_rs1111:N_rs1111","GT_rs8374:N_rs8374")
#Code
unlist(lapply(lapply(strsplit(v1,split = ':'),
                     function(x) sub("_[^_]+$", "", x)),
       function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ':')))
```

Output:

```
[1] "GT:N" "GT:N" "GT:N"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(s, "_\\w+")
#[1] "GT:N" "GT:N" "GT:N"
```

#### data

```
s <- c("GT_rs9628326:N_rs9628326","GT_rs1111:N_rs1111","GT_rs8374:N_rs8374")
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove a word after either `"T"` or `"N"`. Using @ThomasIsCoding's data.

```
gsub('(?<=T|N)\\w+', '', s, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "GT:N" "GT:N" "GT:N"
```